# CSS Columns doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, grid

Hi i couldn't find any working solution here.
I have a 4 columns responsive image grid using CSS columns, but as soon as there is more than 4 images it shows only 3 images in a row and blank space on the side.
All images are 250x250.

```
.mainwrapper { 
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         4;
  column-gap:           0px;
}

.mainwrapper img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

The HTML ( wordpress )

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=24');
if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();     

      echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">';      
      echo '<div class="grid">'; 
      echo '<div class="gridtitle">'; the_title(); echo '</div>';           
      the_post_thumbnail("small-grid");
      echo '</div>';            
      echo '</a>'; 

      endwhile;      
else :  
endif;
```

Whats wrong, please?

Comment: Please add your HTML also

Comment: also if you could reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so, would be helpful

Comment: `body,div{margin:0px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a max-width of 1000. If another img is added, the width would be 1250, so the row would wrap to make 2 rows, 1 with 750px and 1 with 500px. Its the responsive nature. Its not blank, just on the next line

Comment: How can i achieve to get 4 images in the first row and the fifth on the next line?

Comment: @Sugar I don't think you can, i tried. might work with 8 images

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work with 9. This is supposted to be dynamic, sometimes it would work, sometimes don't. Guess the best is to use just 3 columns grid.